# Mixed reality keyboard decimal pad

Tags: unity-game-engine, hololens, mrtk, windows-mixed-reality

Does anybody know how to show up  a decimal pad when using the mixed reality keyboard?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/design/keyboard

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to show up a numeric keypad in Hololens app. If so, it is not supported now for [MixedRealityKeyboard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/mrtk-unity/features/experimental/mixed-reality-keyboard) component.

You can add request via feedback hub for future consideration. For how to post feedback request, you can follow this doc: [Send feedback to Microsoft with the Feedback Hub app](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/send-feedback-to-microsoft-with-the-feedback-hub-app-f59187f8-8739-22d6-ba93-f66612949332)